# Blockquote within Blockquote and creating a multiline quoteblock in vue-quill-editor

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, quill, vue-quill-editor

Basically I want to be able to have a multiline blockquote. The way blockquote works now in quill is that each line break is itself another blockquote.

```
<blockquote>Author name</blockquote>
<blockquote>Another paragraph</blockquote>
```

However I want to be able to nest blocks like p and other blockquotes inside

```
<blockquote>   
    <p><em><small>Author name</small></em></p>   
    <p>Body of text</p>   
    <blockquote>     
        <p><em><small>Author name</small></em></p>     
        <p>another body of text</p>   
    </blockquote> 
</blockquote>
```

I use [vue-quill-editor](https://github.com/surmon-china/vue-quill-editor) in nuxtjs.
Is it possible?
What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: I am having the same issue. Have you been able to solve this?